# Combining multiple rows in SQL Server into one

Tags: sql-server, merge, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID   RefernceID    Field1    Field2    Field3
--   ----------    ------   --------   -------
1     A01           Cat      NULL      Dog  
2     A01           Cat      Fish      NULL  
3     A02           Banana   Apple     NULL 
4     A02           Banana   NULL     Mango
```

I'm trying to get this

```
  ID   RefernceID    Field1    Field2    Field3
  --    ----------    ------   --------   -------
   1     A01           Cat      Fish      Dog  
   3     A02           Banana   Apple     Mango
```

So basically the rows are GROUPED by `ReferenceID` and `Field 1` and then I want them to merge with the NULL's replaced.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add that there are other columns as well (I just didn't mention the, and I still need one of the `ID` values.

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick is to use `max` or `min`, that just ignore `null`s. So if you have only one non-`null` value, `max` will return it. Since you just need one of the `id`s, you could arbitrarily use `min`, which will return the result shown in the question:

```
SELECT   MIN(id), referenceid, field1, MAX(field2), MAX(field3)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY referenceid, field1
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I go about adding other columns that are present in the table? I've modified my OP to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation :

```
select referenceid, field1, max(field2), max(field3)
from table t
group by referenceid, field1;
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I go about adding other columns that are present in the table? I've modified my OP to include that information.

Comment: @AnupamBishui Part of programmer's job is to figure out and/or try out stuffs.  Have you even tried to just add the column to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` and see what you get???  Or probably agrregate the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple aggregation( `max` ) as :

```
select RefernceID, 
       min(ID) as ID,
       max(field1) as field1,
       max(field2) as field2, 
       max(field3) as field3
  from tab
 group by RefernceID
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I go about adding other columns that are present in the table? I've modified my OP to include that information.

Comment: @Anupam welcome friend, I edited due to your last edit.

Comment: The other columns must also be wrapped inside an aggregate function just like field1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @SalmanA what do you mean by `other columns` ..? There's only one column `RefernceID` , which's non-wrapped by an aggregate function, no need to be wrapped since that's the only column in the GROUP BY list.

Comment: sorry, i was responding to OP re adding other columns.